# How can I compile TeX code appearing on websites?

Tags: mathjax

I would like to read pages such as this:
http://www.stmzc.com/complement-of-c-0-in-ell-infty/ 
My browser doesn't seem to be able to compile the TeX code on this page, even though it does compile it on other pages. Is there a way to compile said code so that it would be readable?

Comment: You could also look at the original page: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132520/complement-of-c-0-in-ell-infty

Comment: the site does not support MathML, hence the crude look.

Answer (score 1):

The site you linked scrapes its content from math.SE. Math.SE includes the JavaScript library called MathJAX that can turn TeX code into nicely formatted math, but the scraper site does not.

If you want MathJax to run on every website you visit, that's not a very good idea but it can be done via for example a Greasemonkey userscript. But that's off topic on TeX.SX.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want:

- You want to see the webpage with nice equations

Here, I'm sorry but it is web-site dependent: some websites takes LaTeX-code as content, automatically compiles/processes it using "*the JavaScript library called MathJAX*" as [explained by
marczellm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299527/64454), and display related output (here mathematical writing) as enhanced text or sometimes as picture. Some others just displays what it it: plain text. It's up to the website and not up to you.

- You want to include these nice equations within your `.tex` document.

You can include them in a minimal document, to see what is the result after compiling. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    % (if needed) \usepackage[<options if needed>]{<package name>}
\begin{document}
    % the code you want to test
\end{document}
```

Then save it, compile it twice and... tadaa !

Note that you will sometimes need to load packages to be able to compile macros. For math, I suggest you this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % to enables special characters as input
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % output encoding of characters
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb} % broadly spread packages to handles with maths symbols and functions
\begin{document}
    % the code you want to test
\end{document}
```